# Should the tags *dialects* and *dialectology* be synonyms or merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

It seems to me that the tags *dialects* and *dialectology* are used as synonyms. There are three questions tagged as belonging to *dialectology* and they are also tagged as belonging to *dialects*. Should the two tags become synonyms or does the distinction serve any purpose?

Note: I'm unsure what the common procedure should be here. Please let me know if there is a better way to address this question. Or can I mark them as synonyms myself?

Comment: I think we could come up with some difference and try to force its use, but doubt it would be of much value in this case so merging is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. There should be a synonym in the system for these tags. I just created them and performed the merge.